# Saving python data for an application

Tags: python, file, numpy

I need to save multiple numpy arrays along with the user input that was used to compute the data these arrays contain in a single file.  I'm having a hard time finding a good procedure to use to achieve this or even what file type to use. The only thing i can think of is too put the computed arrays along with the user input into one single array and then save it using numpy.save.  Does anybody know any better alternatives or good file types for my use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize your arrays.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `pickle` and then storing pickled array objects in a storage of your choice, like database or files?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem long ago so i dont have the code near to show you, but i used a binary write in a tmp file to get that done.

EDIT: Thats is, pickle is what i used. Thanks SpankMe and RoboInventor

Answer (score 0):

Numpy provides functions to save arrays to files, e.g. [savez()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html):

```
outfile = '/tmp/data.dat'
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)
np.savez(outfile, x=x, y=y)
npzfile = np.load(outfile)
print npzfile['x']
print npzfile['y']
```